# What can cause such Firefox rendering errors? And how to fix this

Tags: firefox, browser, rendering

I have a poblem with my Firefox, especially on stack exchange pages.

Lot of elements are not visible (mainly text), but visible after hovering mouse. Scrolling page causes some random duplications (like duplicating page fragment instead of moving it).

Also some texts are interpreted badly and shown as unknown utf characters.

Flash also can be hidden until hovering mouse over it.

Question title sometimes changes to whole-page wide black bar.

Some screens:

[image: Broken stack exchange page]

[image: Broken stack exchange page]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a Hardware (GPU) acceleration issue. If you have hardware acceleration enabled, try and disable it and see what happens.

The setting you need to change is in the `Advanced` tab on the FireFox `Options.` Untick `Use hardware acceleration when available,` restart FireFox and see what happens.

If the above doesn't help you could try installing the latest drivers for your graphics card or Rolling back the drivers.

Comment: Turning off acceleration fixed issue. But problems are even with latest drivers. Maybe I will rollback or just wait for newer drivers.

Comment: Good to hear :). It would be best to completely wipe your drivers (driver sweeper) and then install the drivers fresh.